# When do constraints get created for a view created with autoresizing masks?

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, autoresizingmask

For custom UIViews created with autoresizing masks and translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to Yes, at what point precisely does autoresizing become constraints? My guess is that it happens when the view is added to its superview, but happens between the view's calls to its own methods:

```
willMoveToSuperview:
```

and

```
didMoveToSuperview
```

**EDIT:**

UIView.h says:

> by default, the autoresizing mask on a view gives rise to constraints that fully determine the view's position.  Any constraints you set on the view are likely to conflict with autoresizing constraints, so you must turn off this property first. IB will turn it off for you.

I added logging before and after the hooks and surprisingly shows:

```
SpringsNStruts[1195:60b] willMoveToSuperview
SpringsNStruts[1195:60b] self.constraints         (
)
SpringsNStruts[1195:60b] newSuperview.constraints (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8cdbd50 V:[UIView:0x8cdba70(140)]>"
)
SpringsNStruts[1195:60b] didMoveToSuperview
SpringsNStruts[1195:60b] self.constraints         (
)
SpringsNStruts[1195:60b] superview.constraints (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8cdbd50 V:[UIView:0x8cdba70(140)]>"
)
```

This isn't intuitive. So where are the constraints that should be created from autoresizing masks translated to constraints? I haven't found any documentation that explains what is going on here. Anyone know?

Comment: How about implementing all those hooks, call super and NSLog(@"%@", self.constraints);

Comment: I gave that a try @danh and made edits above.

Comment: 1) Why do you care? If this is other than just curiosity, then you're almost certainly doing something wrong. This is an implementation detail on which you can't rely. 2) It's probably during (or at least around the time of) the call to `-updateConstraints`, which is called by `-updateConstraintsIfNeeded` if the view was marked as needing it, which is called before the layout pass (or manually), which is done before the display pass (or manually).

Comment: @KenThomases the reason (which was sort of hard for me to articulate until now) is because I may need to add autoresized views onto autolayout views and the autoresized views may need to change sizes. I think the size changes will always be done before the autoresized view becomes a subview of an autolayout view. I know it's not good to mess with frames in autolayout, so I'm trying to understand this scenario and see if it's safe.